# Is it still a force-out if baserunner made it?

Tags: rules, baseball

Say there is a runner on first base. The batter hits it to the outfield and the baserunner advances to second base but over-runs the bag by making an aggressive turn. On the throw back, he gets tagged out trying to get back to second base. Is it ruled a force-out or, because it was the baserunner's fault, is it ruled single and the baserunner out at second base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would not be ruled a force out but would be scored as a put out much like if the outfielder had thrown it to third to tag an advancing runner there. I'd assume the batter would be given a single since it was hit to the outfield. If the official scorer viewed there could have reasonably been an out made at first, it would be ruled a fielder's choice.

Comment: Thanks; that's exactly what I imagined. I'm just not sure which rule number to cite in the MLB rulebook to verify this.

Comment: @AhaanS.Rungta 5.09(b)(6) is best since it specifies the force out is possible "...before he touches the next base".  Once the base is touched, the force is off.